ECM: Adding I(0) variable
I have an ECM model where the long-term relation is between $y$ and $x_1$ that are both I(1) and cointegrated, i.e.
$y(t) = a + b.x_1(t) +\epsilon(t)$
To this long-term relation, I want to add $x_2$ which is I(0). This makes no sense to add $x_2$ to the short-term response. The business logic says that $x_2$ should impact $y$, not $\Delta y$. In other words, without $x_1$, $y$ would be driven by $x_2$ and in that case $y$ would be I(0). Building a model without $x_2$ does not make sense and including $x_2$ is the short-term response does not make sense. The intuition is that $x_2$ impact $y$. So I am focusing on the long-term equation.
Mathematically, having
$y(t) = a + b.x_1(t) + c.x_2(t) + \mu(t)$
sounds correct. $y$ and $x_1$ are cointegrated so adding $x_2$ should have no impact. The residual is still I(0). This is a departure for the textbook/classic ECM framework so my questions are:

Do you see any issue with this type of equation?
Where can I find literature on the topic? The literature is focus on I(1) processes and I cannot find reference about adding I(0) variable.
Alternatively, could I build the LT with $x_1$, then regress the residual $\epsilon$ on $x_2$ (both are I(0)), and move to the short-term component? Doing so, what would be incorrect?
What alternative approach would you suggest?

